# Call parent controller function in route

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using **ngRoute**, and I need to call parent controller function in my route controller. (I do not use $scope)
Part of index.html:

```
<div class="col-lg-12" ng-controller="IndexController as index">

    <div ng-view>
    </div>

</div>
```

And parent controller:

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('project')
        .controller('IndexController', IndexController);

    function IndexController() {
        var vm = this;

        vm.hello = function() {
            console.log("Hello from parent controller");
        }
    }
})();
```

How can I call hello() in route controller?

Comment: don't understand what you want to achieve?

Comment: I have index.html, and templates in views folder. In some routes I need to call parent controller function. How can I do that? Parent controller is IndexController, and it is applied to div in index.html. That div contains ng-view container.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add an empty dependency array in your module declaration..

```
.module('project', [])
```

Then you need to invoke your function.. like this using a button.

```
<div class="col-lg-12" ng-controller="IndexController as index">

  <div ng-view>
    <button ng-click="index.hello()"></button>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: 1.Without dependency list, ngRoute will not work 2.I need to call function inside **controller**

Comment: 2.I need to call function **from** route controller